# Transaction synchronization in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a small Spring Boot application with `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, and `postgresql` as dependencies.

I'm able to use the `@Transactional` annotation and use JPA to fetch and save entities to the database. However, if I were to add `afterCommit`/`afterCompletion` hooks via registering a synchronization, it gives an `IllegalStateException` saying that `Transaction synchronization is not active`.

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
     new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCommit() {
            //this doesn't get called
            log.info("do something here");
        }
    });
```

Doing `TransactionSynchronizationManager.initSynchronization();` gets rid of the error, but the hooks don't get called (eg: the `afterCommit` hook doesn't get called even though the transaction has committed.)

Any clues on how to debug this?

Comment: what do you want to do after commit?

Comment: new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that I had forgotten to include the build plugin that is used to create the AoP-proxies for beans having @Transactional annotations.

In the absence of this plugin, no proxies would get generated, and the code would run non-transactionally; except for when it enters the `JpaRepository` methods where it would create a short-lived transaction for the duration of the call (such as `save`/`findAll`/`delete`).

This is the plugin that I missed including in my pom.xml (this got generated in the pom output by the spring initializr (https://start.spring.io/) but I didn't notice it at first and didn't copy it over into my pom)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `@TransactionalEventListener` annotation. It supports hooks BEFORE_COMMIT, AFTER_ROLLBACK, AFTER_COMPLETION, AFTER_COMMIT and AFTER_ROLLBACK.

More info in this post: [Better application events in Spring Framework 4.2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2).

Answer (score 0):

After transaction had been started TransactionManager is clearing
synchronization collection, you should do this after transaction has been started.